# mySQL column to column copy based on a range

Tags: mysql

I need to copy values from column 1077 to column 1086 only where the values are Null in 1086 or even if the ID is less then 4910.

I thought this would work, but no luck:

```
UPDATE
s762017_survey_19427
SET 19427x28x1086=19427x28x1077
WHERE id  < 4910
```

Data:

```
id  submitdate  19427X28X1077   19427X28X1086
4900    9/17/2019 11:47 Y       NULL
4901    9/17/2019 12:25 Y       NULL
4902    9/17/2019 12:56 Y       NULL
4903    9/17/2019 13:49 Y       NULL
4904    9/17/2019 13:28 Y       NULL
4905    9/17/2019 13:45 Y       NULL
4906    9/17/2019 13:47 Y       NULL
4907    9/17/2019 13:49 Y       NULL
4908    9/17/2019 13:54 N       NULL
4909    9/17/2019 14:20 Y       NULL
4912    9/17/2019 15:13         A1
4915    9/17/2019 15:28         A1
4918    9/17/2019 15:44         A3
4919    9/17/2019 15:45         A3
4921    9/17/2019 15:51         A1
4922    9/17/2019 15:59         A3
4923    9/17/2019 17:15         A3
4924    9/17/2019 17:05         A3
4925    9/17/2019 17:24         A1
4929    9/17/2019 19:55         A1
4930    9/17/2019 19:52         A1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider changing the names of your columns, that are very unusual. Column names that start with number or contain special character need to be quoted with backticks, otherwise a syntax error is raised.

From your description of your question, it also look like you are missing a condition in the `where` clause (it's hard to tell, however, if it should be `or` or `and`):

```
UPDATE `s762017_survey_19427`
SET `19427x28x1086`= `19427x28x1077`
WHERE id < 4910 and `19427x28x1086` is null
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems as thought the Simulate Query feature ahs a bug, when I hit Go this worked.